# Minor alignment issue in the Closing > Duplicate - close vote count in Firefox browser

Tags: bug, design, firefox

In earlier today when I try to flag a post as duplicate, I see a minor alignment issue with the close vote count in the **Closing > Duplicate** modal dialog. The display issue is due to the particular length of the post title. I can't see the same issue with other posts, since those post titles are having different length.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Screenshot]

But I can reproduce the scenario when I manually set the post title as single line and the vote count to be displayed in the last character of the line, then it will display in the next line.

**GIF for the same:**

[image: GIF]

**Configurations:**
Mozilla Firefox: 56.0b3 (32-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Zoom: 100%